# Dunford-Pettis like properties for Banach spaces of operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-spaces, banach-algebras, operator-spaces

Let $E$ be a Banach space and $A\subseteq B(E)$ be a Banach subspace of operators on $E$.
Suppose $A$ satisfies the property (RCC) given below:
$$
\left.\begin{array}{l}
(x_n)\subseteq A \textrm{ bounded} \\
\xi_n\to 0\textrm{  weakly in }E\\
\end{array}\right\}
\Rightarrow x_n\xi_n\to 0\textrm{  weakly in }E. \hspace{2cm}\textrm{(RCC)}
$$

Property (RCC) is equivalent to

1. The map $\phi_g:E\to A^*$, $\phi_g \xi = \xi\otimes g$ is completely continuous for each $g\in E^*$, where $\langle x, \xi\otimes g\rangle = g(x\xi)$ for each $x\in A$.
2. $\{x^*g: x\in A, \|x\|\leq 1\}\subseteq E^*$ is an $L$-set for $E$, for each $g\in E^*$.

We can show that if $A$ contains all rank-1 operators, then $A$ has property (RCC) if and only if $E$ has the Schur property. Clearly, if $E$ has the Schur property, then every subspace of $B(E)$ has property (RCC).

As an example, $A=\{\hat{a}: a=(a_n)\in c_0\}\subseteq B(\ell^2)$ where $(\hat{a}\xi)_n = a_n\xi_n$ for each $\xi=(\xi_n)\in\ell^2$ has the property (RCC) above.

**Question 1:** Let $E$ be reflexive, let $A\subseteq B(E)$ be irreducible (in the sense that $A\xi = E$ for each $\xi\in E$) with property (RCC). Suppose $A$ is maximal wrt. (RCC) in the sense that if $A\subseteq A_2\subseteq B(E)$ and $A_2$ has property (RCC), then $A=A_2$. Does $A$ have the Dunford-Pettis property?

**Question 2:** Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $A\subseteq B(H)$ be an irreducible operator space with property (RCC). Does the $C^*$-envelope of $A$ have the Dunford-Pettis property?